# Characterising functions of bounded variation by their modulus of continuity

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Given a a.e. finite measurable function $ \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$, define the essential modulus of continuity, $M(f): \ \mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R+ \to \mathbb R$ by
$$
M(f) (x, e)=\sup_{m(A) = 0} \Big\{d \geq 0\,\big|\, f\big(B_d (x) - A\big) \in [f(x) - e, f(x) + e]\Big\}
$$

It can be shown (details here: https://justpaste.it/7eltw) that $M$ is well defined a.e. in the product measure and does not depend on choice of representative.

Can we characterise functions of bounded variation by the behaviour of $M$? That is, if $S$ is the set of measurable functions, find some subset $V$ of $M(S)$ such that a function has bounded variation iff it is in $V$.

Comment: **Note:** the dependence from $x$ is necessary: for any increasing, continuous, not Lipschitz, *uniform* modulus of continuity, $\omega:[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$ such that $\omega(0)=0$ and $\limsup_{t\to0}\omega(t)/t=+\infty$ there is an $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|\le \omega(|x-y|)$ and $f$ has infinite variation on $[0,1]$.